# Deleting all rows from table that share the same ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-ase

I have the following table:

```
Name     |   ID  |  date    |
Login    |   1   | somedate |
Command  |   1   | somedate |
Command  |   1   | somedate |
Login    |   2   | somedate |
Command  |   1   | somedate |
Command  |   2   | somedate |
Logout   |   1   | somedate |
Command  |   2   | somedate |
```

I want to delete from the table everything between a login and a logout that share the same ID, but keep everything else there. The somedate fields are datetime. There could be more logins/logouts in the table and there will be Logins that don't have a corresponding logout. I want that to remain there because the logout will appear eventually.

I was thinking of using a cursor. Which would be the best approach for performance too? The final table could have a few millions of rows.

After the delete the table should look like this:

```
Name    |  ID  |  
Login   |  2   |
Command |  2   |
Command |  2   |
```

Edit: Delete everything between a Login and a Logout, including the rows with Login/Logout.

Comment: Like chris updated, try to get all those IDs having 'Logout' entry. Do a direct delete.

Comment: Your result confuses me, do you want to delete ID 1 completely because it has both a login and a logout appearance?

Comment: @RichBenner Yes, exactly, including the Login and the Logout.

Comment: Ok, your wording is confusing "I want to delete from the table everything between a login and a logout". Between wouldn't include the login and logout commands, I'll update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @RichBenner Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that every logout has a corresponding login you could try this:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Name LIKE 'Logout'
)
```

The result would be:

```
Name    |  ID  |
Login   |  2   |
Command |  2   |
Command |  2   |
```

If you want to have the rows with "Login" and "Logout" too you could do this:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Name LIKE 'Logout'
)
AND Name NOT LIKE 'Login'
AND Name NOT LIKE 'Logout'
```

You would get this result:

```
Name    |  ID  |
Login   |  1   |
Login   |  2   |
Command |  2   |
Logout  |  1   |
Command |  2   |
```

Comment: It would appear that the ID is not a primary key in this example so this will delete ALL records, including the Login and Logout, which i don't think is what OP is asking for

Comment: @Milney Look at his expected result. He wants to delete login and logout too.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ambiguous cases (what happens if there are commands with no matching login? if the login is on the same day as the logout are we assuming the logout is after the login? etc.) but this should give you a starting point;

It deletes all records which are **not** login or logout records, where the records have an **earlier** login, and a **later** logout record for the same Id;

```
WITH TestData AS (
    SELECT 'Login' as Name, 1 AS ID, cast('01/01/2000' as date) as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Command' as Name, 1 AS ID, cast('02/01/2000' as date) as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Command' as Name, 1 AS ID, cast('03/01/2000' as date) as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Logout' as Name, 1 AS ID, cast('04/01/2000' as date) as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Command' as Name, 1 AS ID, cast('05/01/2000' as date) as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Command' as Name, 2 AS ID, cast('01/01/2000' as date) as Date
)
DELETE FROM TestData td1
-- Delete any records which are not login or logout
WHERE Name <> 'Login' AND Name <> 'Logout'
-- Where there is an earlier Login
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 from TestData td2 where td2.Name = 'Login' AND td1.Id = td2.Id AND td2.Date <= td1.Date)
-- and a later logout
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 from TestData td3 where td3.Name = 'Logout' AND td1.Id = td3.Id AND td3.Date >= td1.Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's make some test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (Name varchar(7), ID int, Date datetime)
INSERT INTO #TestData (Name, ID, Date)
VALUES
 ('Login',1,'2016-06-23 12:00:00')
,('Command',1,'2016-06-23 12:05:00')
,('Command',1,'2016-06-23 12:10:00')
,('Login',2,'2016-06-23 12:15:00')
,('Command',1,'2016-06-23 12:20:00')
,('Command',2,'2016-06-23 12:25:00')
,('Logout',1,'2016-06-23 12:30:00')
,('Command',2,'2016-06-23 12:35:00')
```

I'd use a query like this. The joined query returns all rows for a particular ID that are between the login and logout datetime. It will not delete anything for ID 2 as there isn't a logout for that one yet.

```
DELETE TD
FROM #TestData TD
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT a.Name, a.ID, a.Date
FROM #TestData a
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ID, Date
            FROM #TestData
            WHERE Name = 'Login'
          ) lin
ON a.ID = lin.ID
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ID, Date
            FROM #TestData
            WHERE Name = 'Logout'
          ) lout
ON a.ID = lout.ID
WHERE a.Date BETWEEN lin.Date AND lout.Date
) b
ON TD.Date = b.Date
AND TD.ID = b.ID
AND TD.Name = b.Name
```

The result after this has run will be

```
Name    ID  Date
Login   2   2016-06-23 12:15:00.000
Command 2   2016-06-23 12:25:00.000
Command 2   2016-06-23 12:35:00.000
```

Edit: Updated my answer so that it now deletes the login/logout command too.

Comment: Working perfectly!

Comment: Feel free to upvote any answers that have helped you. If one solves the specific issue then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I miss understood your question on my first post, edit to correct:

```
delete from yourTable
where id in (select yt.Id from yourtable yt
        inner join yourtable yt2 on yt2.Id = yt.Id and yt2.Name like 'Logout'
        where yt.Name like 'Login')
```

The above should delete everything from your table where a login has a corresponding logout

Comment: I think he just didn't explain him self well.

Comment: It would appear that the ID is not a primary key in this example so this will delete ALL records, including the Login and Logout, which i don't think is what OP is asking for

Comment: @Milney to me it appears OP only wants to keep the records which have a Login but no Logout. This will delete all records with the same Id, the no primary key would be a problem but that Id could be from a unique connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(id)  into @id from your_table where Name = 'Logout'; -- will give you all user id that need to delete
delete from your_table where id in (@id );
```

Comment: It would appear that the ID is not a primary key in this example so this will delete ALL records, including the Login and Logout, which i don't think is what OP is asking for

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. OP mentioned everything BETWEEN Login and Logout, but in expected result OP don't want to get Both entries. 
Think he needs to edit the post :)